# How to Iterate Tuples though OrderedDict

Tags: python-3.x

I have a list of OrderedDict as follows:

```
    power = [OrderedDict([('i', '1'), ('p', '-9.11')]), OrderedDict([('i', '2'), ('p', '-9.11')]), OrderedDict([('i', '3'), ('p', '-9.1')]), OrderedDict([('i', '4'), ('p', '-9.1')]), OrderedDict([('i', '5'), ('p', '-9.1')]), OrderedDict([('i', '6'), ('p', '-9.1')]), OrderedDict([('i', '7'), ('p', '-9.09')]), OrderedDict([('i', '8'), ('p', '-9.09')]), OrderedDict([('i', '9'), ('p', '-9.09')]), OrderedDict([('i', '10'), ('p', '-9.09')]), OrderedDict([('i', '11'), ('p', '-9.08')]), OrderedDict([('i', '12')]]
```

I want the get the 'i' number such as 1,2,3 and also the 'p' value '-9.11', '-9.1' ..
I have tried

```
for i,j in power:
    print(i,":", j)
```

but it returns `i:p`
Any idea how to execute that?

Answer (score 2):

You could try:

```py
for i, j in (d.values() for d in power):
    print(f'{i} : {j}')
```

Assuming each `OrederedDict` in `power` has a length of 2.

Answer (score 2):

There are no tuples in your `OrderedDict`. When you do call `OrderedDict(iterable)` (e.g. in your case the `iterable` is a `list`), it expects that each element of `iterable` gives you a key-value pair. So in your case, each element of the list is a tuple, and the first element of that tuple is the key, the second item is the value to set in the `OrderedDict`.

When you do `for item in power`, each `item` is an `OrderedDict`.
When you try to unpack it in that same line with `for i, j in power`, the `OrderedDict` called `item` gets unpacked into the variables `i` and `j`. When you unpack a dict, you get its keys, so the variable `i` gets the first key (which is the string `"i"`), and the variable `p` gets the second key (which is the string `"p"`). You *could* unpack the values using [ssp's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71315377/843953), but I suggest you should actually access the keys of the dict.

Once you have `item`, you can simply access its keys using `item[key]`. So do:

```
for item in power:
    print(item["i"], ":", item["p"])
```

If you want to create a new dictionary where the values of the `i` key are keys and the values of the `p` key are values, do:

```
d = dict()
for item in power:
    key = item["i"]
    value = item["p"]
    d[key] = value
```

Or, as a dict comprehension:

```
d = {item["i"]: item["p"] for item in power}
```

Which gives:

```
{'1': '-9.11',
 '2': '-9.11',
 '3': '-9.1',
 '4': '-9.1',
 '5': '-9.1',
 '6': '-9.1',
 '7': '-9.09',
 '8': '-9.09',
 '9': '-9.09',
 '10': '-9.09',
 '11': '-9.08'}
```

If you want the keys to be integers and the values to be floats, explicitly convert them:

```
d = {int(item["i"]): float(item["p"]) for item in power}
```